XQuerytree returns wrong number of child windows
I am trying to get the number of top level windows aka children of the root window in Xlib using XQuerytree. It is just working fine when only experimenting with basic X utilities such as Xterm or Xeyes but the num_top_level_windows contains a completely wrong number for apps using GTK or QT frameworks (e.g. with only KeepassXC open, i apparently have 5 top level windows). Here is the relevant code snippet.
Window returned_root, returned_parent;
Window* top_level_windows;
unsigned int num_top_level_windows;
XQueryTree(
        display_,
        root_,
        &returned_root,
        &returned_parent,
        &top_level_windows,
        &num_top_level_windows);  
printf("\n\n N: %d\n", num_top_level_windows);

root_ and display_ are references to the root window and the display (obtained via XOpenDisplay and DefaultRootWindow(display_) and should be working fine. I am using a nested Xephyr X server session on gentoo linux. I really wonder why this "error" occurs and how can i get the true number of children windows. Thank you in advance!
